# fabric.js adding a Image object to a group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I think/hope this is a simple question:

Is it possible to add an Image object to a fabric.group like i did with other elements here:

```
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: "lightblue",
    stroke: "black",
    width: 155,
    height: 20,
    id: 'infosquare'
});



var text = new fabric.Text(label.toString( ), {
    fontSize: 11,
    fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",
    fill: "black"

});



var stairInfo = new fabric.Group([rect, text], {
    left: x,
    top: y,
    borderColor: 'yellow',
    id: 'stairInfo',
    hasControls: false,
    selection: false,
    hasRotatingPoint: false
});
```

Every example i found does add the image directly to the canvas like this:

```
var target_pin = fabric.Image.fromURL('pics/pin_target.png', function (target_pin) {
        canvas.add(target_pin.set({
            top: top,
            left: left,
            hasControls: false,
            selection: false,
            hasRotatingPoint: false,
            scaleX: 0.07,
            scaleY: 0.07,
            id: 'target_pin'

        }));


        canvas.renderAll();
        canvas.bringToFront(target_pin);


    });
```

but i dont want that, i wanna add the image to the group above and the return the whole group to another function. 
I hope someone could help me.

Comment: it should be able to be added to a group. have you tried it and it has not worked? Can you post a code snippiet I can run of your attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this works for me:

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    var myimg;
    var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
        left:0,
        top: 0,
        fill: 'green',
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
    });
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 50,
        top: 0,
        radius: 50,
        fill: 'blue',
    });

    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/site_assets/challengepost.png', function (oImg) {
        myimg = oImg.setLeft(100);
        var group = new fabric.Group([triangle, circle, myimg], {
            left: 50,
            top: 50,
        });
        canvas.add(group);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

**Edit:** To answer the second question, the main thing to remember here is that you can't do anything with the image object until the image has finished loading. In my original answer the callback function is only executed after image loading, and then the image object is added to the group/canvas. If you want to do this later in your code you would need to make a manual check that the image loading is complete, something like this:

```js
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var myimg;
    var group;
    var imageLoaded = false;

    function addGroup() {
        if (!imageLoaded) {
            // Image not loaded yet, need to wait
            setTimeout(function () { addGroup() }, 100);
            return;
        }
        // Ok we have the image, can add to group/canvas
        group = new fabric.Group([hi, rect, myimg], {
            left: 50,
            top: 50
        });
        canvas.add(group);
    }

    var hi = new fabric.Text('hello.', {
        left: canvas.getWidth() / 3,
        id: 'greetings'
    });

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        fill: 'red',
        width: 10,
        height: 100,
        id: 'square'
    });

    var myimg;
    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/site_assets/challengepost.png', function (oImg) {
        myimg = oImg.setLeft(100);

        // Set flag when image loading complete
        imageLoaded = true;
    });

    // Do some other stuff here

    addGroup();
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: "lightblue",
    stroke: "black",
    width: 155,
    height: 20,
    id: 'infosquare'
});

var text = new fabric.Text(label.toString( ), {
  fontSize: 11,
  fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif",
  fill: "black"

});

var target_pin = fabric.Image.fromURL('pics/pin_target.png', function (target_pin) {
    var img1 = target_pin.set({
                  top: top,
                  left: left,
                  hasControls: false,
                  selection: false,
                  hasRotatingPoint: false,
                 scaleX: 0.07,
                  scaleY: 0.07,
                 id: 'target_pin'
});
var stairInfo = new fabric.Group([rect, text, img1], {
  left: x,
  top: y,
  borderColor: 'yellow',
  id: 'stairInfo',
  hasControls: false,
  selection: false,
  hasRotatingPoint: false
});
 canvas.add(stairInfo);

});
```

Try this.